# NSPredicate == query

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data, nspredicate

I'm trying to use nspredicate to find a managed object whose attribue's vale is == to a value I want to check.

I know for certain that the value is in my data model.

This is what I have tried so far but the results array count is always zero.

```
-(BOOL)checkIfFavouriteExists:(NSString *)data
{
    BOOL returnvalue;

    NSFetchRequest *fetchReq = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];

    NSString *attributeName = @"userid";
    NSString *attributeValue = data;
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K == '%@'",
                              attributeName, attributeValue];

    //setting the predicate to the fetch request 
    [fetchReq setPredicate:predicate];

    [fetchReq setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Favourites" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext]];

    NSMutableArray *resultArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:[self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchReq error:nil]];

    if([resultArray count]>0)
    {
        returnvalue=YES;

    }    else
    {
        NSLog(@"No records");
        returnvalue=NO;
    } 

    return returnvalue;
}
```

**EDIT**

The problem seems to be with my query format.

This works though?

```
NSExpression *exprName = [NSExpression expressionForKeyPath:@"userid"];
NSExpression *exprVal = [NSExpression expressionForConstantValue:data];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSComparisonPredicate predicateWithLeftExpression:exprName
                                                            rightExpression:exprVal 
                                                                   modifier:NSDirectPredicateModifier 
                                                                       type:NSEqualToPredicateOperatorType 
                                                                    options:0];
```

I dont understand why one works and the other does not. They both do the same thing right?

Comment: Have you tried to catch the error from -executeFetchRequest:error: ?

Comment: You've tried it with single `=` in the predicate format?

Comment: Try this, `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%@ = %@",
                              attributeName, attributeValue];
`

Comment: @SImon, I found I solution but I will try your also :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't put your variables in quotes. The [documentation on Parser Basics](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001795-SW2) states:

> Single or double quoting variables (or
>   substitution variable strings) cause
>   %@, %K, or $variable to be interpreted
>   as a literal in the format string and
>   so prevent any substitution.

This should do it:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"userid == %@", attributeValue];
```

You can read more about predicates in the [Predicate Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/predicates.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001798-SW1).